# C - semantics to do with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

A very short question; how does one refer to 'names' below?

```
char *names[] = { 
            "Alan", "Frank",
            "Mary", "John", "Lisa"
};
```

Is 'names' (a)a pointer to an array of strings?, or (b)an array of pointers to strings?

I've noticed that if the address of "Alan"(and 'names') is x, then the address of "Frank" is x+(0x08), the address of "Mary" is x+(0x10), and so on.  So for this reason I'm leaning more towards (a).

Comment: names is an array of pointers to characters.

Comment: http://www.cdecl.org/ helps

Comment: `[]` has priority over `*`, so that the declaration should be read as _"`names` is an array of pointers to `char`"_.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo no, [] has a higher priority

Comment: Thanks Manül!  That website is amazing!

Comment: @Manül yeah, just swapped them in the first part. I guess I need more coffee :)

Comment: Actually, *names[] is a pointer to an array of char pointers.  This is because each of the strings resolves to a pointer to a location in .const when the string actually exists.  If I were writing this, I would write it as 'char names[] = { ... };  Then you have an array 'name[]' that contains pointers to the actual strings.  Then each string could be referenced as *name[x] to access the actual string entry.  As it is, you have a pointer to an array 'name[]' that contains pointers to strings.  There is no need for the extra dereferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As intro first of all: **There are not "string"s in C.**

What in C commonly is called a "string" really is an array of characters (`char`s) with at least one of it's elements carrying a `'\0'`, the "string"-terminator, also known as the `0`-termination marking the end of the "string".

So a "string" is a `char` array like this:

```
char s[42] = "alk"; /* with char[0] == 'a', char[1] == 'l', char[2] == 'k' and char[4] == '\0' */
```

This declares `s` to be an array of `char`, which could carry 42 `char`s, that may be a "string" with a maximum length of 41 `char`s, as one `char` needs to carry the terminator (see above).

---

You mentioned two types in your question:

- (a) a pointer to an array of strings
- (b) an array of pointers to strings

#### Refering (a):

A pointer to an array of string needs to have an array of strings to point to:

Let's define it:

```
char stringarray[3][42]; /* An array of 3  "string"s, each with a max length of 41+'\0'-terminator. */
```

A pointer to this would be:

```
char (*pstringarray)[3][42] = &stringarray; /* A pointer to an array of 3 elements of "string"s with a max length of 41 (see above). */
```

#### Referring (b):

An array of pointers to "string"s needs some "string"s to point to:

```
char s1 = "alk";
char s2 = "football";
char s3 = "champion";
```

Now lets define the array of pointers to "string"s pointing to the "string"s defined above:

```
char * pointerarray[4] = {
  s1,
  s2,
  s3
}
```

The latter is equal to:

```
char * pointerarray[] = {
  "alk",
  "football",
  "champion",
  NULL
}
```

with the 1st three elements referring to some `char`-arrays ("string"s) and the last element carrying `NULL`(the null-pointer-value) to indicate the end of the array. Please note: In the first example the latter, the 4th element, the 4th pointer is implcitily set to all `0`s, as if an initialiser misses to provide values for what it is initialising those (missed) bytes are all set to to `0`.

#### Conclusion

The OP's example matches proposal (b), so it's:  **an array of pointers to "string"s**.

Answer (score 0):

**char*** means Pointer to character

**[]** means array

**char* name[]** means array of pointers to characters

String in C is an array of characters. For the string-literal like "Alan" the compiler adds a 0x0 at the end.

For performance reasons, the compiler aligns the reserved memory on the register width (32-bit = 4-byte). That's why the actual string "Alan"+ 0x0 requires 8 bytes instead of 5.

**EDIT**

Sorry for confusion!

I think the confusion was: *address of "Alan"(and 'names') is x*

**Address of "Alan" is not the address of names! Address of *pointer to "Alan" after initialization* is the address of names.**

If you define such a variable, the compiler does three things:

- allocates 2 different blocks of memory:

  - One for holding the pointers in the array = 5 * sizeof(char*)
  - Another for storing the literals ("Alan", ...)
- initializes the pointers with proper addresses of the data in initial values.
  names[0] = start of "Alan"-string etc.

The pointers are of cause aligned in the array - apparently for your machine 8-byte wise (64-Bit) If you mean by address the address of the pointer, then of cause the difference will be always 8 (on your machine)

Comment: Thanks Valentin.  If Alan was really, really long, would "Frank" start at x+0x10 instead of x+0x08?  I tried making "Alan" really long, and that didn't happen.

Comment: The length of "strings" in not visible for name, because it does not store whole strings, but only points to the beginning of strings (remember in this case string is also an array)

Comment: I see, zoska.  But what if "Alan" was very, very long.  Could it flow into, and overwrite the space for "Frank"?

Comment: @AndyP: I've changed something in the answer. I hope it's more clear now. The array names and the content provided in the initialization are not the same - they are 2 different variables (more accurately one variable and one constant). As the pointers of the array point to a constant memory, you can't change the names. However you can change the pointer in names to point to another c-string. Usually, when initializing in such way, use const char *names[], so that the compiler will help you avoiding later exception at run time when you'd try to modify pointers content.